# Initialization safety in java

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, final

Just to make sure I understand the concepts presented in java concurrency in practice.

Lets say I have the following program:

```
public class Stuff{
    private int x;

    public Stuff(int x){
        this.x=x;
    }

    public int getX(){return x;}
}

public class UseStuff(){
    private Stuff s;

    public void makeStuff(int x){
        s=new Stuff(x);
    }

    public int useStuff(){
        return s.getX();
    }
}
```

If I let multiple threads to play with this code, then I'm not only in trouble because s might be pointing to multiple instances if two or more threads are entering to the makeStuff method, but even if just one thread creates a new Stuff, then an other thread who is just entered to useStuff can return the value 0 (predefined int value) or the value assigned to "x" by its constructor.

That all depends on whether the constructor has finished initializing x.

So at this point, to make it thread safe I must do one thing and then I can choose from two different ways.

First I must make makeStuff() atomic, so "s" will point to one object at a time.

Then I either make useStuff synchronized as well which ensures the I get back the Stuff object x var only after its constructor has finished building it, OR i can make Stuff's x final, and by this the JMM makes sure that x's value will only be visible after it has been initialized.

Do I understand the importance of final fields in the context of concurrency and JMM?

Comment: Assuming an instance of UseStuff is shared between the threads, then: no, s will always point to exactly one instance at a time. Your problem is that you won't be sure which instance it is, as multiple threads might override that reference. By setting it to final, you're making sure that the reference s is set when UseStuff is initialized, and no one ever will change it on any thread.

Comment: Sorry, just noticed you wanted to make x final. So in that case you're guaranteeing that once an instance of Stuff is created, its field x can never be changed anymore. The field s can still be overwritten in this case with a new Stuff, but at least you can be sure that a particular instance of Stuff won't ever have its x changed by any Thread.

Answer (score 3):

> Do I understand the importance of final fields in the context of concurrency and JMM?

Not quite. The spec [writes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5):

> `final` fields also allow programmers to implement thread-safe immutable objects without synchronization. A thread-safe immutable object is seen as immutable by all threads, even if a data race is used to pass references to the immutable object between threads. This can provide safety guarantees against misuse of an immutable class by incorrect or malicious code

If you make `x` final, this guarantees that every thread that obtains a reference to a `Stuff` instance will observe `x` to have been assigned. It does not guarantee that any thread will obtain such a reference.

That is, in the absence of synchronization action in `useStuff()`, the runtime is permitted to satisfy a read of `s` from a register, which might return a stale value.

The cheapest correctly synchronized variant of this code is declaring `s` volatile, which ensures that writes to `s` happen-before (and are therefore visible to) subsequent reads of `s`. If you do that, you need not even make `x` final (because the write to `x` happens-before the write of `s`, the read of `s` happens-before the read of `x`, and happens-before is transitive).

Answer (score 2):

Some answers claim that `s` can only refer to one object at a time. This is wrong; because there is no memory barrier, different threads can have their own notion about the value of `s`. In order for all threads to see a consistent value assigned to `s`, you need to declare `s` as `volatile`, or use some other memory barrier.

If you do this, you won't *need* to declare `x` as `final` for the correct value to be visible to all threads (but you might still want to; fields shouldn't be mutable without a reason). That's because the initialization of `x` *happens-before* the assignment of `s` in "source code order," and the write of the volatile field `s` *happens-before* other thread reads that value from `s`. If you subsequently modified the value of a non-final field `x`, however, you could run into trouble because the modification isn't guaranteed to be visible to other threads. Making `Stuff` immutable would eliminate that possibility.

Of course, there's nothing to stop threads from clobbering the value assigned to `s`, so different threads could still see different values for `x`. This isn't really a threading issue though. Even a single thread could write and then read different values of `x` over time. But preventing this behavior in a multi-threaded environment requires *atomicity,* that is, checking to see whether `s` has a value and assigning one if not should appear as one indivisible action to other threads. An `AtomicReference` would be the best solution, but the `synchronized` keyword would work too.

Comment: Saying that s can have more than one value at a given time may be correct in a sense, but that way of thinking about it won't help you to write correct code.  How do you prove that thread X is reading the "right" value?  The better way to think about it is, the variable only has one value at a time, but it is hard to know what time it is.  Java's has rules for that:  The "happens before" rules tell you how to properly synchronize the program so that you can _prove_ what time it is (relative to events in other threads) when some given thread executes some specific line of code.

Comment: @jameslarge That's an equivalent way to look at it. I don't see how it's better. Go with whatever makes sense to you.

Comment: It's better because it's the point of view from which Java's "happens before" rules are written.  The "happens before" rules talk about threads that may or may not experience the same field updates in the same order, and they tell us how to limit that re-ordering (i.e., how to "synchronize") when it's important.  If you chose instead to take an omniscient view of what _actually_ happens in real-time, then you have to invoke words like "cache" and "flush" and "invalidate".  That viewpoint helps you to see the problem, but it is contrary to the formal rules that help you _solve_ the problem.

Comment: I agree it's important to understand *happens-before* relationships and synchronization points, which is why I discuss them in my answer. But, "the first step is to admit you have a problem." For a newbie struggling for an initial grasp, having other people claim the problem doesn't exist, and failing to discuss solutions, is unhelpful.

Comment: Ah! Now I see.  Yes.  The Java Memory Model could seem to be a bit confusing to somebody who does not understand the reality that underlies the model.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to protect by making things synchronized? Are you concerned that thread A will call makeStuff and then thread B will call getStuff afterwards and the value won't be there? I'm not sure how synchronizing any of this will help that. Depending on what problem you are trying to avoid, it might be as simple as marking s as volatile.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you're doing there. Why are you trying to create an object and then assign it to a field? Why save it if it can be overwritten by other call to `makeStuff`? It seems like you use UseStuff both as an proxy and as a factory to your actual `Stuff` model object. You better separate the two:

```
public class StuffFactory {
  public static Stuff createStuff(int value) {
    return new StuffProxy(value);
  }
}

public class StuffProxy extends Stuff {
   // Replacement for useStuff from your original UseStuff class
   @Override 
   public int getX() {
     //Put custom logic here
     return super.getX();
   }
}
```

The logic here is that each thread is responsible for creation of their own Stuff objects (using the factory) so concurrent access no longer an issue.